# Asymptotic rate of the largest order statistic.

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, order-statistics, rate-of-convergence

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $P$. Let $g$ be a measurable function with $P g = 0$ and $P g^2 = 1$. Show that $\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|g(X_i)| = o_p (\sqrt{n})$.

I read this claim in a proof but couldn't figure it out myself.

EDIT: $P g = 0$ and $P g^2 = 1$ mean: $E[g(X_1)] = 0$ and $E[g(X)^2] = 1$. $o_p(\cdot)$ is small oh pee notation: $X_n = o_p(Y_n)$ means that $X_n = Y_n R_n$ and $R_n \stackrel{P}{\to} 0$.

Comment: What is meant by $Pg=0$ and $Pg^2=1$?  Do you mean $E[X_i]=0$ and $E[X_i^2]=1$?  What does $o_p(\sqrt{n})$ mean?

Comment: @Michael See the edit. I updated it.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking, if $\{G_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with $E[G_i]=0, E[G_i^2]=1$, then show $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\max_{i\in \{1, ..,. n\}}|G_i|\rightarrow 0$ in probability as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Michael Yes. You can simplify the claim. I wrote down what is exactly written in the book.

Comment: The Markov/Chebyshev inequalities seem the most direct, but are too weak for this scenario.  If you define $f(z) = z^2P[|G|\geq z]$ you can actually show $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} f(z)=0$, which you can then use for this problem (using $f$ function at the place you would ordinarily use Markov/Chebyshev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G_i=g(X_i)$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Note
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|G_n|/n^{1/2}>\epsilon)=\sum_nP(G_n^2/\epsilon^2>n)\le\int_0^\infty P(G_1^2/\epsilon^2>t)\,dt=E[G_1^2/\epsilon^2]=1/\epsilon^2<\infty
$$
Therefore, the second Borel Cantelli lemma implies $P(|G_n/n^{1/2}|>\epsilon\text{ infinitely often})=0$. This holds for all $\epsilon>0$, allowing you to conclude $|G_n|/\sqrt{n}\to 0$ almost surely.

You can then use the following fact: if $a_n$ is any sequence such that $a_n/\sqrt{n}\to 0$, then it follows $\frac1{\sqrt n}\max_{1\le i \le n}a_i \to 0$. Thus, you can conclude $\frac1{\sqrt n}\max_{i\le n} |G_i|\to 0$ almost surely, and therefore also in probability.

Comment: Can you explain your argument ``if $a_n$ is any sequence ...''? The maximum is taken over $n$ random variables with $n \to \infty$. How do you justify it?

Comment: A sequence of random variables is just a random sequence of numbers. Saying that $|G_n|/\sqrt n\to 0$ says that with probability one, the random sequence $a_1/\sqrt 1,a_2/\sqrt 2,\dots$ which actually occurs will converge to $0$. Using the fact, you can then conclude $\frac1{\sqrt n}\max_{i\le n} a_i\to 0$. Since this is true for almost all outcomes, it follows that the convergence holds almost surely.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: +1 Nice proof for an even stronger result (with almost surely).